# How to preset values in an input type box? (Express.js web app)

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have some input type boxes like this in a Jade file:

```
 label(for="slider1") Speed
 input(type="number", id="tbSS", class="tb_GPSslider", value=0)
```

I want to pass in a variable value to the input area, like this:

```
 label(for="slider1") Speed
 input(type="number", id="tbSS", class="tb_GPSslider", value=newValue)
```

How do you do this in Jade? I am passing in values already via a `res.render()` in my handler like this:

```
exports.dashboard = function(req, res){
    res.render('dashboard', {newValue: req.session.newValue});
}
```

Comment: That looks correct. If it's not working, try replacing req.session.newValue with a hard coded string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

```
value=#{newValue}
```

`#{}` for server-side variables with jade/express

Comment: Makes sense, except that I'm getting an `Unexpected token ILLEGAL` error on that line when I try to assign value=#{newValue}.

Comment: Try wrapping that in quotes

Comment: `value="#{newValue}"` is the same as `value=newValue`